# Showing wrong C prototypes as build warnings

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-c++

Is it possible for Visual C++ (i.e. Visual Studio) to report any incorrect extern function prototypes as build errors?

I have a Visual Studio C project compiled with `/Wall` ("Enable all Warnings") and `/WE` ("Treat Warning as Errors"). However, if I define a wrong extern prototype for an existing function, which is really a run-time disaster, it will not even print an informational message and the program will likely fail at runtime.

For example, if I have `test.c` defined like this:

```
void some_function(int *x, int *y, int *z)
{
    *z = *x + *y;
}
```

And now let's say in `main.c` somebody puts a "hand crafted" `extern` with a wrong definition, instead of including `test.h`:

```
// compiles fine with /wall /e, no warnings or messages
extern void some_function(int *x);

int main(void)
{
   int x = 5;
   some_function(&x);  // <- write access violation in runtime
   return 0;
}
```

Obviously, writing an `extern` definition outside of a header file which is included in the external compilation unit is a bad idea, and possibly there is a use case where changing the prototype would allow somebody to profit, but I would be much happier if Visual Studio would force me to write a `#pragma` around such code. At the same time, using `/wall /we` makes "[C4710](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(C4710)&rd=true) `printf` was not inlined" a fully fledged build error.

Of course, note that this would fail immediately, if written in the same file:

```
void some_function(int *x); 

// Warning C4029: declared formal parameter list different from definition
void some_function(int *x, int *y, int *z)
{
    *z = *x + *y;
}
```

Is there a way to prevent these mistakes from happening in Visual Studio (apart from adhering to a coding standard, obviously)?

Comment: @Ðаn: well IMHO linker should be able to detect this, i.e. treat it as an unresolved symbol.

Comment: @Ðаn: well, that's one option, so you might add this as an answer. I thought perhaps I was missing some linker options. In my case, it won't work, unfortunately, since C code has lots of `extern "C"` stuff which should require rewriting.

Comment: @Ðаn: no doubt about that, yes. :) I was playing with some legacy code and wanted to call a "private" C function to unit test something which wasn't exposed through the header, so I wrote an extern because I didn't want to modify the header.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In **C** (not C++), the linker knows nothing about argument types as names aren't mangled, all `some_function()`s are the same regardless of arguments.

Since you're using Visual Studio, one way to get what you're looking for is to compile your C code as C++.  This will generate mangled names, which in turn will generate a link-time error.

Comment: Note that arbitrary C code is not C++ code — there are things you can write in C that are not valid, or mean something different, in C++.  That said, it is one way to deal with the problem, and the differences are not necessarily that big if you write the C code with C++ in mind.